# Searching for word and finding it's line number LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, search, directoryinfo

Hey all I found the following code [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882649.aspx) and was wondering if it's possible if I can also get the line number where the word appears by using the LINQ query or by some other means?

```
Dim startFolder = "C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\project"
Dim fileList = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder).GetFiles("*.vb", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim queryMatchingFiles = From file In fileList _
                             Where file.Extension = ".vb" _
                             Let fileText = GetFileText(file.FullName) _
                             Where fileText.Contains(word2Search) _
                             Select file.FullName

Debug.Print("The term " & word2Search & " was found in:")

For Each filename In queryMatchingFiles
    Debug.Print(filename)
Next
```

The code works for finding the word but I would really like to be able to know what line it was found on as well.

Any help would be great!

Comment: What if the term appears multiple times in a file?

Comment: @FarhanAnam then I would like it to let me know what line(s) those are within that document. **(example: Lines 15, 22, 108)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LINQ `Select` method [has a overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that passes in the index of the item.

```vb
Dim startFolder = "C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\project"
Dim matches =
    From f In Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "*.vb", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    From l In File.ReadLines(f).Select(Function(x, i) New With { .Line = x, .LineNo = i + 1})
    Where l.Line.Contains(word2Search)
    Select FileName = f, LineNo = l.LineNo, Line = l.Line
```

Matches will be an `IEnumerable` of objects with `FileName`, `LineNo` and `Line` properties.

**UPDATE**

To get the file name and an array of the matching line indexes, you could do something like this:

```vb
Dim matches =
    From f In Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "*.vb", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    From l In File.ReadLines(f).Select(Function(x, i) New With { .Line = x, .LineNo = i + 1})
    Where l.Line.Contains(word2Search)
    Select File = f, LineNo = l.LineNo
    Group By File Into g = Group
    Select FileName = File, LineNos = g.Select(Function(x) x.LineNo).ToArray()
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable` of objects with `FileName` and `LineNos` properties.

Finding the positions of the matches in the lines requires a few more changes, since `Contains` just returns a `Boolean`.  You can use `Regex.Matches` to find the positions of matches in the line, so:

```vb
Dim matches =
    From f In Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "*.vb", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    From l In File.ReadLines(f).Select(Function(x, i) New With { .Line = x, .LineNo = i + 1})
    Where l.Line.Contains(word2Search)
    Select File = f, LineNo = l.LineNo,
        MatchPositions = Regex.Matches(l.Line, Regex.Escape(word2Search)).Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(x) x.Index)
    Group By File Into g = Group
    Select FileName = File, Matched = g.Select(Function(x) New With { x.LineNo, .Positions = x.MatchPositions.ToArray() }).ToArray()
```

After this, you end up with an `IEnumerable` of objects with `FileName` and `Matched` properties (unfortunately, VB.NET didn't like that being called `Matches` because that clashes with the `matches` variable, but you can play with that to your liking).  The `Matched` property is an array of objects with `LineNo` and `Positions` properties, with `Positions` being an array of the indexes into the strings (zero based, so add a `+ 1` in there if you like).

Comment: Your comment on the question clarifies what you are looking for, so I think this is a little off.  I'll update in a minute to show just returning the file name and matching line numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the code but I am not returning any results now using your code?

Comment: @StealthRT Did you pick up the edit I made to correct the search term?  It was hard coded in the first version to match my test data.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Mark Is it possible to return an array of integers as the line numbers? I mean, for each file, there should be an array. And any possibility of positions in the line?

Comment: @Mark yes it must have been the original posting. I copied what you currently have and tried again and it works! *Is Farhan's request possible as well?*

Comment: @FarhanAnam See update to get the match positions in each line.